# pd.to_datetime not producing in the correct format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, machine-learning

I have dataset:

```
    Date      Max_Temp  Min_Temp
0   01-01-11    27.0    14.2
1   02-01-11    26.4    15.8
2   03-01-11    27.8    15.4
3   04-01-11    26.4    13.6
4   05-01-11    26.4    15.6
5   06-01-11    25.8    15.2
6   07-01-11    26.0    13.0
7   08-01-11    27.0    13.2
8   09-01-11    28.8    12.8
9   10-01-11    27.2    13.6
10  11-01-11    27.8    10.2
11  12-01-11    27.2    9.4
12  13-01-11    28.0    8.6
13  14-01-11    28.2    8.8
14  15-01-11    28.0    10.4
```

Here 01 to 15 is date in `Date` column of month `1`. But when I am doing pd.to_datetime for further processing to extract the Day , Month, Year from the Date column, pd.to_datetime itself shows wrong format:

```
data["Date"]= pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]) 
data.head(15)

    Date      Max_Temp  Min_Temp
0   2011-01-01  27.0    14.2
1   2011-02-01  26.4    15.8
2   2011-03-01  27.8    15.4
3   2011-04-01  26.4    13.6
4   2011-05-01  26.4    15.6
5   2011-06-01  25.8    15.2
6   2011-07-01  26.0    13.0
7   2011-08-01  27.0    13.2
8   2011-09-01  28.8    12.8
9   2011-10-01  27.2    13.6
10  2011-11-01  27.8    10.2
11  2011-12-01  27.2    9.4
12  2011-01-13  28.0    8.6
13  2011-01-14  28.2    8.8
14  2011-01-15  28.0    10.4
```

It is seeing the month as the date. Please currect me. Thanks!!

Comment: data["Date"]= pd.to_datetime(data["Date"],dayfirst=True)

Comment: Can pass `dayfirst` or explictly state the `format`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

If this doesn't help you you can try with `format` argument:

```
pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: not the downvoter but your format is wrong

Comment: Now format is correct